# T-SQL IF Block Not Executing Though Conditions Are Met

Tags: sql-server-2008, if-statement

I've got the following SQL statement that I am working on.  I've trimmed it down to the parts necessary to illustrate the problem.

```
DECLARE @mwareId as int = 9647,
@startDate as datetime = '2011-07-20',
@endDate as datetime = '2011-07-20'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpInvoiceList', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpInvoiceList

-- Get base invoice list for customer
SELECT   invoiceId
        ,invoiceNumber
        ,customerId
        ,customerName
        ,customerCode
        ,createDate
        ,lastModifiedDate
        ,invoiceDate
        ,totalInvoiceAmount
        ,statusId
        ,isPaid
INTO #tmpInvoiceList
FROM    Invoice.Invoice

-- Apply date range if applicable
IF ( @startDate != NULL AND @endDate != NULL )
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM #tmpInvoiceList
    WHERE invoiceDate NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
END

SELECT * FROM #tmpInvoiceList
```

I have the @startDate and @endDate variables set to date values.  The problem is that the if block that applies the date range to the temp table is not executing, though neither of the two variables are null, and I can't find a reason for this.

Comment: Equality/inequality comparisons with `NULL` will always yield `UNKNOWN` which in this context means your expression evaluates to `FALSE`. @hspain's answer is correct - you need to use `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, TSQL doesn't support the != operator for null checks.  Try this:

```
IF ( @startDate IS NOT NULL AND @endDate IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: Actually, it does support !=.  But your solution still works, because the problem is that NULL does not play nice with equality (or inequality) operators.

Comment: I suppose that's what I meant.  Doesn't support != for null checks.  Thanks for the clarification, though.

Comment: @kuru kuru na That's exactly it, I didn't realize that the != operator doesn't work correctly for nulls.

Answer (score 0):

`IS [NOT] NULL` is the right way to compare value with `NULL`. All of (`NULL` != `NULL`) , (1!= NULL), (NULL =NULL) evaluate as `NULL`(false)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= NULL`

```
IF ( @startDate IS NOT NULL AND @endDate IS NOT NULL )
...
```